# Is there a way to create something like a reverse proxy for PPTP?

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp, reverse-proxy

On my home network I have a PPTP VPN server. My router however does not allow me to port forward the default PPTP port because it is "already forwarded". I know it isn't but that doesn't matter now. I have forwarded it using a different port.

As Windows only connects using the default port I now want to use a server in a datacenter to host a reverse proxy to the PPTP VPN on my home network so I can use the server's IP and the default PPTP port and the server forwards the traffic to the VPN server at my home network.

I know that PPTP is insecure but for my application nothing else will work.

Comment: PPTP is insecure and has been deprecated by Microsoft for years. Now may be a good time to switch to a proper VPN protocol.

Comment: I know that but for my application only PPTP will properly work @Spiff

Comment: What _is_ your application? (Windows 98?)

Answer (score 1):

Not for PPTP specifically, no. But on the other hand, it's not even needed – just have *two* VPN connections and let the server act as an IP router between them.

That is:

- ExternalServer acts as the VPN hub;
- HomeDevice is permanently connected to the VPN;
- ExternalServer has a route to your home subnet;
- when MobileDevice connects to ExternalServer's VPN and tries to reach home LAN, the server will route that via HomeDevice.

(Also, pick a VPN stack that's not going to be killed off within a few months. OpenVPN, IKEv2 with strongSwan, or DTLS with ocserv are good choices.)

Comment: So basically run a VPN client on the external server which connects to the VPN server at home and then run a VPN server on it which the portable devices use to connect then?

Comment: Okay. Just running an OpenVPN client and PPTP server on the same machine does not seem to work (clients connecting to the PPTP server can not access the internet or anything but the server). What exactly did you mean?

Comment: Yes, mostly like that, just make sure the server actually has IP forwarding etc. enabled. (Approach it as if setting up a router between 3 physical LANs – one subnet for OpenVPN, one for PPTP, and the server as router.)

Comment: As soon as I start the OpenVPN client on the external server there is no internet or network connection for clients connecting to the PPTP server on it anymore though

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use PPTP!

[It's horribly insecure in Windows](https://www.schneier.com/academic/pptp/faq.html?).

Those involved in the Linux implementation say [don't use it](http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/protocol-security.phtml).

Instead, if you are running Windows Server 2008 or newer, you can set up an SSTP (Secure Socket Tunnelling Protocol) VPN which uses the standard TCP 443 port.  Or if you prefer an open source solution, check out OpenVPN.

Comment: I have reasons for using PPTP and not something else ;)

The server is running Linux Debian BTW ;)

Comment: Understood.  I updated my answer to cover Linux as well. Others are certainly free to answer how to get this set up, but I'm leaving my answer as a warning for others considering use of PPTP.

Comment: alright. I already knew about it but my new case doesn't allow for anything else. But of course it is good to have a warning there ;)